# Cassandra: how can i select a row by the third primarykey in Cassandra when the table is with WITH COMPACT STORAGE?

Tags: cassandra, storage

```
CREATE TABLE gsg.callback_queue (
    key blob,
    column1 bigint,
    column2 text,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, column1, column2)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC, column2 ASC)
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 43200
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = 'NONE';
```

I execute the below query:

```
select * from callback_queue 
where column2='167-df8fb9d8-13b0-418e-b21b-f5599c7819fc' allow filtering;
```

but it throws an exception like this:

> message="PRIMARY KEY column "column2" cannot be restricted (preceding
>   column "column1" is not restricted)

then I use second index like this:

```
create index idx callback_queue(column2);
```

but it throws a exception like this:

> Secondary indexes are not supported on PRIMARY KEY columns in COMPACT
>   STORAGE tables

So, how cant I get a raw with column2?

Comment: s there any good reason you use compact storage? Legacy code that definitly needs the old thirft interfaces? If not migrate to non compact storage if possible and use CQL3.

If you cant migrate denormalize for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your table, column `key` is partitioning key, so it should be present while performing `where` clause queries.
You can either change your schema or you can create `materialised view` from parent table which supports your given query.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW gsg.callback_queue_by_column2 AS
    SELECT key, column1, column2, value
    FROM gsg.callback_queue
    WHERE key IS NOT NULL AND column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 IS NOT NULL AND value IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (column2, key, column1);
```

Now following query will work.

```
select * from callback_queue_by_column2 where column2='167-df8fb9d8-13b0-418e-b21b-f5599c7819fc';
```

Answer (score 0):

In a primary key the first part is the partition key and the second part is the clustering column.

Primary key (partition key, Clustering Column);

While defining Primary keys you can use either compound key or composite key.

Compound key
A multi-column primary key is called a Compound Key :  Primary key (partition key, Clustering Column);

Composite key
A partition key based on multiple columns : Primary key ((partition key1, partition key2));

If you use composite key then the where clause in your query should contain all the columns used for defining the partition key.

In your case the primary key column "key" should be part of the where clause.

Comment: you said: "If you use composite key then the where clause in your query should contain all the columns used for defining the partition key."
here if in where clause my query has single column, then will it be an efficiency issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to not to use ALLOW FILTERING clause, especially in a production database with lots of transactions (I don't know if this is your case). In your case, all of the nodes in the cluster will do heavy operations to answer the query.

And, as the error says, you cannot create an index for primary key columns. If you really need creating an index on column2, you should  not use column2 as a part of primary key.

If you want Cassandra to perform well, it is really important to have a good data model. So I advice you to learn, at least basics of, Cassandra data modelling.

In Cassandra, it is a good practice to model your data by considering your queries in advance, i.e. it is good to know your queries first before starting data modelling. Also denormalize your data model if necessary. In Cassandra, it is OK to have duplicates of your data in multiple tables.

So, in your case, I guess you should create another table and this table should have a partition key of column2. And you should duplicate your data in this new table too.